# Ajax request is not working it seems

Tags: jquery, ajax

i have following ajax code... it seems to not working...

```
$('form').submit(function () {
    var email = $('#useremail').val();
    var name = $('#username').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Landing2/mail.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            email: email,
            name: name
        },
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        },
    });
});
```

my dir sturcutre is

```
htdocs
 Landing2
    index.php (From where i am making request")
    mail.php
```

anything wrong in this?

Comment: what error you're getting?

Comment: Are you getting any console errors? You should remove the final `,` after the final `}` of your Success function.

Comment: Check the network tab in your browser developer tools and see if the response is returning a successful status (usually `200 OK`)

Comment: url: 'mail.php', test this.

Comment: If the file is in the same folder I believe you can simply use the Filename (i.e. `url: 'mail.php',` instead of `url: '/Landing2/main.php',`)

Comment: @Nunners no console error i am getting...

Comment: When you send the form, is the page refreshed or not?

Comment: When you submit the form, does the page refresh / is the user re-directed? If so then you will need to make your Ajax call synchronous instead of asynchronous.

Answer (score 3):

Your requested url should be this:

```
url: 'mail.php',
```

this will work for you.

Comment: don't you think if using ajax then form submission should be stopped.

Comment: @Jai don't know what you want to say.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few issues with this, your properties you are passing to your Ajax call are incomplete. Either add a final property (i.e. `error: function() {}`) or Remove the final `,` from the end of your properties.

Also if the request location is in the same directory as the current location, you can just specify the file name (i.e. `url: 'mail.php'`)

Example code :

```
$('form').submit(function () {
    var email = $('#useremail').val();
    var name = $('#username').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'mail.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            'email': email,
            'name': name
        },
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're running your script with JQuery.

Jquery doesn't need the full path from root to send a query. 
If your site URL is http://www.example.com/htdocs/Landing2/index.php

- If you specify a `/` in your URL, the path will be taken from your root URL.

  ```
  $.ajax({
            url : '/htdocs/Landing2/mail.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {email:email,name:name},
            success: function (data){
                alert(data);
            },
        });
  ```
- If you don't specify the `/` it will take in the same level of folder.

  ```
   $.ajax({
            url : 'mail.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {email:email,name:name},
            success: function (data){
                alert(data);
            },
        });
  ```
- Or you can put the full URL of your website.

  ```
  $.ajax({
            url : 'http://www.example.com/htdocs/Landing2/mail.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {email:email,name:name},
            success: function (data){
                alert(data);
            },
        });
  ```

Every solutions leads to the same effect, it only depends on how you want to show the URL in your code.

Comment: Usually the `htdocs` folder is used by Apache as the root folder of your server, so you wouldn't have to include it in your URL.

Comment: Decent explanation of this but since he is specifying from the root of the site, (`/Landing2/mail.php`) this description does not solve the OP's problem as it would work the same if it was `/Landing2/mail.php` or `mail.php`.